# TextView's corner becomes white when clicked

Tags: android, textview, statelistdrawable

I use the following code snippet to show a `TextView`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);

GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{0xffff0000,0xffff0000});
gd.setCornerRadius(10);
GradientDrawable gd1 = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{0xff00ff00,0xff00ff00});
gd1.setCornerRadius(10);
StateListDrawable background = new StateListDrawable();
background.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, gd1);
background.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, gd);
tv.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
tv.setClickable(true);
```

in the normal state, its appearence is ok:
[image]

but when it is clicked, the four corners will become white, see this:
[image]

How can I avoid this?

Comment: add selector for the textview

Comment: what do you mean?Can u show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Create a text_bg_selector.xml file under your drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_bg" /> <!-- pressed -->
        <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/focused_bh" /> <!-- focused -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_bg" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Then set your TextView's background to this:

```
android:background="@drawable/text_bg_selector"
```

**Edit for your code:**

Since setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated, you must check it and write setBackground like this:

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{0xffff0000,0xffff0000});
gd.setCornerRadius(10);
GradientDrawable gd1 = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{0xff00ff00,0xff00ff00});
gd1.setCornerRadius(10);
StateListDrawable background = new StateListDrawable();
background.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, gd1);
background.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, gd1);
background.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, gd);
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    t.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
} else {
    t.setBackground(background);
}
t.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: I can't use xml resource as the colors are not fixed values. BTW, I think there's no difference using xml or constructing the background at runtime. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not really. Just setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated so you must do an SDK check. Will update my answer for it.

Comment: The new API `setBackground` simply calls `setBackgroundDrawable`, so I don't think it causes that strange behavior

Comment: well, this code is working perfectly for me in every version (tried with 8,11 and 17 devices). There shouldn't be any problem with the background like the way I wrote since it is working normally. May be there is some other code that you didn't put here, which causes the problem.

Comment: I should have realized it...Thanks anyway